# How to make custom node type animation data show in dope sheet

Tags: python, dopesheet, pynodes

I have created a custom node type, using the blender custom_nodes.py template.

I have made a custom node, with a IntProperty with ANIMATABLE set as an option of the IntProperty.

i can insert a keyframe, and that works fine... and the fcurve is showing up under:

```
bpy.data.node_groups['NodeTree'].animation_data.action.fcurves[0]
```

but the 'NodeTree' animation data does not show up inside the dopesheet, or the fcurve editor.

is there something that i have to do to make my custom node tree's animation data to show up in the dopesheet and fcurve editor?

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be a limitation of the current setup. The dopesheet and graph editor don't display items from custom node trees.